# Recursively extract contents of (nested) parentheses in string

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that extracts the words contained in parentheses into their own array, recursively to account for nested parentheses.

So for "((a b) ugh (one two)) pi", i'd like that to translate to the following structure:

```
[
  [
    [
      "a",
      "b"
    ],
    "ugh",
    [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
  ]
  "pi"
]
```

To that end, I've written the following function:

```
function shitshow(hell) {
    var ssparts = [];
    var done = false;
    for (i in hell) {
        let part = hell[i];
        switch(part) {
            case "(":
                ssparts.push(shitshow(hell.slice(i+1)));
                break;
            case ")":
                done = true;
                break;
            default:
                ssparts.push(part);
        }
        if (done) break;
    }
    return ssparts;
}

console.log(shitshow("((developer or engineer) or (nurse or doctor)) and manager"));
```

It doesn't work. The array it returns for me (I'm testing this on Node 4):

```
[
  "",
  [
    "doctor"
  ],
  [],
  "developer",
  "or",
  "engineer"
]
```

Been wrestling with this for a while. Any ideas?

---

EDIT: As @Oriol mentioned below in this post's comments, my posted code does not produce my posted output. This is because I forgot to mention/include where I RegEx'd the initial string into an array of words and non-alphanumeric symbols. Sorry about this. Because @Oriol has already posted a working solution, I am including this notice instead of updating my code, so that his posted solution can stand.

Comment: love those function names

Comment: There is no way your code produces that output. You are pushing single characters to the array.

Comment: @Oriol good point, I forgot to add that I'd used a RegEx to split the string into an array of words and no alphabetic symbols. Will update as soon as I'm at my laptop again.

Comment: @Oriol or I guess since you've already posted your solution I'll update my question to reflect string input so your answer can stand. Thanks, btw, for your response.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I usually do something like the following.

An outer function receives the string as argument and declares outer variables used to iterate it.

The work is done in a recursive inner function which iterates until `)`.

This way all new strings I create are included in the returned array. No useless work is done.

```js
function shitshow(str) {
  var i = 0;
  function main() {
    var arr = [];
    var startIndex = i;
    function addWord() {
      if (i-1 > startIndex) {
        arr.push(str.slice(startIndex, i-1));
      }
    }
    while (i < str.length) {
      switch(str[i++]) {
        case " ":
          addWord();
          startIndex = i;
          continue;
        case "(":
          arr.push(main());
          startIndex = i;
          continue;
        case ")":
          addWord();
          return arr;
      }
    }
    addWord();
    return arr;
  }
  return main();
}
console.log(shitshow("((developer or engineer ) or (nurse or doctor)) and manager"));
```

```css
div.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Here is a bug somewhere, this leaves the last letter out in the example above. Hit the "Run code snippet" and it returns:  `"and", "manage"` without the R.

Comment: @Ciantic I managed to remedy this. I added a parameter to the addWord function `addWord(incLastChar)`. I amended line #8 to `arr.push(str.slice(startIndex, incLastChar ? i : i-1));`. Then I amended line #26 to `addWord(true);`.

Answer (score 7):

One way may be to reformat it into JSON and then let JSON.parse() do all the work.  Something like:

```js
function blah(string) {
 string = string.replace(/\(/g, "[");
 string = string.replace(/\)\s/g, "], ");
 string = string.replace(/\)/g, "]");
 string = string.replace(/\s+/, ", ");
 string = "[" + string + "]";
 string = string.replace(/[^\[\]\,\s]+/g, "\"$&\"");
 string = string.replace(/" /g, "\", ");

 return JSON.parse(string);
}

console.log(blah("((a b) ugh (one two)) pi"));
```

EDIT:  Fixed some problems with regular expressions & posted as running code.  Works with the test string.

```
[[["a","b"],"ugh",["one","two"]],"pi"]
```

As it stands, it will not cope if your string does not have a space between ")" and a word, nor if there is a space between two "))", but if your input format is known and rigid as above then it would be fine.  Otherwise, further regular expression tweaking or substituting could deal with that.

Depending on where the source of your text is from, if it is possible to get it in JSON from the source, that would make it a trivial one-liner solution. I only mention this because your strings are similar to JSON already, but they may be from a source where you don't have that much control over the format.

Answer (score 5):

Just been looking for a more complete solution due to the "manage" vs "manager" bug that Ciantic found in Oriol's answere.

```js
function shitshow(str) {
  var i = 0;
  var trailingWhiteSpace = str[str.length - 1] === " ";
  function main() {
    var arr = [];
    var startIndex = i;
    function addWord() {
      if (i-1 > startIndex) {
        arr.push(str.slice(startIndex, i-1));
      }
    }
    while (i < str.length) {
      switch(str[i++]) {
        case " ":
          addWord();
          startIndex = i;
          continue;
        case "(":
          arr.push(main());
          startIndex = i;
          continue;
        case ")":
          addWord();
          return arr;
      }
    }
    if(!trailingWhiteSpace){
      i = i + 1;
      addWord();
    }
    return arr;
  }
  return main();
}
console.log(shitshow("((developer or engineer ) or (nurse or doctor)) and manager"));
```

```css
div.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for a formula I needed to process. Here's my riff off of 'Son of a Beach's answer:

```js
function formulaToArray(formula='') {
  const step1 = formula
    .split(/([\(\)\+\-\*\/])/)
    .map(x => x.trim())
    .join(' ')
    .replace(/\)\s\)/g, '))')
    .replace(/\(/g, '[')
    .replace(/\)\s/g, '], ')
    .replace(/\)/g, ']');

  const step2 = '[' + step1 + ']';

  const step3 = step2
    .replace(/[^\[\]\,\s]+/g, '"$&"')
    .replace(/" /g, '", ')
    .replace(/\,[\s]+\]/g, ']');

  return JSON.parse(step3);
}

console.log(formulaToArray('((developer or engineer )or (nurse or doctor)) and manager'));
// [
//   [
//     ['developer', 'or', 'engineer'], 
//     'or', 
//     ['nurse', 'or', 'doctor']
//   ], 
//   'and', 
//   'manager'
// ]
```

This takes care of the problems he cited: ')word' and ') )', though I guess not ') ) )'