# Javascript, RegEx to split the string to multidimentional array between parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling to split the following input string to array:

`'((Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) AND (Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25)) OR (Application = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110) OR (Application = imap AND "Server Port" != 143) AND (Application = imap OR "Server Port" != 143)'.split(/\(([^)]+)\)/g)`

Yields:

`["", "(Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25", " AND ", "Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25", ") OR ", "Application = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110", " OR ", "Application = imap AND "Server Port" != 143", " AND ", "Application = imap OR "Server Port" != 143", ""]`

But what I want the result should look like:

`["", "(Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) AND (Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25")", OR ", "Application = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110", " OR ", "Application = imap AND "Server Port" != 143", " AND ", "Application = imap OR "Server Port" != 143", ""]`

notice the 1st index `"(Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) AND (Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25")"`

Any suggestions to achieve this in RegEx?

**EDIT**
Formatted:

I'm having following input string

```
(
   (
     (App = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) 
     OR 
     (App = pop3 AND "Server Port" == 20)
   ) 
   AND 
     (App = smtp AND "Server Port" != 35)
 ) 
OR 
(App = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110) 
AND 
(
   (App = imap AND "Server Port" != 143) 
   OR 
   (App = pop3 AND "Server Port" == 20)
) 
AND (App = imap OR "Server Port" != 143)
```

wants to transform into:

```
[
    [
         [
           'App = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25', 
           'OR', 
           'App = pop3 AND "Server Port" == 20'
         ], 
      'AND', 
      'App = smtp AND "Server Port" != 35'
    ], 
   'OR', 
   'App = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110', 
   'AND', 
   [      
     [
       'App = imap AND "Server Port" != 143', 
       'OR',
       'App = pop3 AND "Server Port" == 20'
     ]
   ], 
   'AND', 
   'App = imap OR "Server Port" != 143'
]
```

Comment: Could you share what was regex you've tried?

Comment: The expected array you gave is not a valid javascript array.

Comment: I have formatted the input and output.

Comment: I have tried `.split(/\(([^)]+)\)/g)`

Comment: So your expected output is an nested array, I really don't think regex is appropriate tool to archive this, maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477850/recursively-extract-contents-of-nested-parentheses-in-string could be helpful for you.

Comment: I have actually used another technic to `split(/\s*[\(\),]+\s*/g)` generate the flattened array (1D) then I will create nested array if the element of the array is empty to produce nested array. Still seeking to improve it if any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many suggested the better way to do is to create a flattend array. And, deal with each inner array with (split). But, Still for the sake of argument if you want to do it by `regex` this is one odd / awkward solution to consider:

```js
    var str = '((Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) AND (Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25)) OR (Application = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110) OR (Application = imap AND "Server Port" != 143) AND (Application = imap OR "Server Port" != 143)';

    var final = str.replace(/\((?!\()/g,"['")        //replace ( with [' if it's not preceded with (
               .replace(/\(/g,"[")               //replace ( with [
               .replace(/\)/g,"']")              //replace ) with '] 
               .replace(/\sAND\s/g,"','AND','")  //replace AND with ','AND','
               .replace(/\sOR\s/g,"','OR','")    //replace OR with ','OR','
               .replace(/'\[/g,"[")              //replace '[ with [
               .replace(/\]'/g,"]")              //replace ]' with ]
               .replace(/"/g,"\\\"")             //escape double quotes
               .replace(/'/g,"\"");              //replace ' with "
    console.log(JSON.parse("["+final+"]"))
```

Comment: Though its hacky (I will enhance it) its more generic than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps:

```
\(([^O]+|[^(]+)\)
```

The complete code will be something like this:

```js
console.log('((Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) AND (Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25)) OR (Application = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110) OR (Application = imap AND "Server Port" != 143) AND (Application = imap OR "Server Port" != 143)'.split(/\(([^O]+|[^(]+)\)/g))
```

Comment: this logic I have already tried but it fails: `'((Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) AND ((Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) OR (Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25))) OR (Application = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110) OR (Application = imap AND "Server Port" != 143) AND (Application = imap OR "Server Port" != 143)'.split(/\(([^O]+|[^(]+)\)/g)`