# Recursive function for brackets in a string in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, recursion

I'm working on a js function for checking if a number is answering a specific condition.
(For example: you can check if the number is in between 2 other numbers in a simple way, and more)

I'm trying to add a functionality where I'll be able to include brackets(multiple times) in the rngStr string param and it'll return the correct answer.
(For example: I'll pass (75, "0...100 & [70...80, 0...100] & 30...50") and it'll return false)

I tried searching and I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477850/recursively-extract-contents-of-nested-parentheses-in-string) but it didn't seem to work for this case.

I also tried creating a new recursive function to split the content of each pair of brackets in the strings but it also didn't work(I'm not sure how to continue with it).
Here is the function I tried to use:

```
function recInRange(value, rngStr){
        let currentIndex = 0;
        let depth = 0;
        let prevStartIndexs = [];
        let depthPerIndex = [];
        let depthPerString = [];

        (function inRangeRecursive(){
            if(rngStr[currentIndex] === "["){
                depth++;
                prevStartIndexs.push(currentIndex);
            }
            if(rngStr[currentIndex] === "]"){
                depthPerIndex.push({depth: depth, startIndex: prevStartIndexs[prevStartIndexs.length-1], endIndex: currentIndex});
                depthPerString.push({depth: depth, text: rngStr.slice(prevStartIndexs[prevStartIndexs.length-1]+1, currentIndex)});
                prevStartIndexs.pop();
                depth--;
            }
            currentIndex++;
            if(currentIndex < rngStr.length){
                inRangeRecursive(value,rngStr);
            }
        })()
        console.log(depthPerString);
        return depthPerIndex;
    }
    
    console.log(recInRange(100, "[[0...100], [100...200]] & 20...30"));
```

And here is my complete code without the function.

```js
const andRegex = /[ ]*[&][ ]*/gim
const orRegex = /[ ]*[,][ ]*/gim
const betweenRegex = /[ ]*[...][ ]*/gim

//These lines below works great.

console.log(inRange(100, "...100"))
//value(100) is smaller or equal to 100 = true

console.log(inRange(100, "0..."))
//value(100) is bigger or equal to 0 = true

console.log(inRange(100, "0...100"))
//value(100) is between or equal 0 to 100 = true

console.log(inRange(100, "0...100, 150...200"))
//value(100) is between or equal 0 to 100 or 150 to 200 = true

console.log(inRange(100, "0...100 & 70...120"))
//value(100) is between or equal 0 to 100 and 70 to 120 = true

console.log(inRange(75, "0...100 & 70...80, 0...100 & 30...50"))
//value(75) is between or equal (0 to 100 and 70 to 80) or (0 to 100 and 30 to 50) = true


//The result of the inRange function in the comment below should
//be false.

//console.log(inRange(75, "0...100 & [70...80, 0...100] &
//30...50"))
//value(75) is between 0 to 100 and (70 to 80 or 0 to 100) and 30 
//to 50 = false.


function inRange(value, rngStr) {
  let orArray = splitWithCondition(rngStr, orRegex)
  let orResult = false
  for (let j = 0; j < orArray.length; j++) {
    let andArray = splitWithCondition(orArray[j], andRegex)
    let andResult = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < andArray.length; i++) {
      let betweenArray = splitWithCondition(andArray[i], betweenRegex)
      console.log(betweenArray)
      let isBigger = betweenArray[0] ? value >= +betweenArray[0] : true
      let isSmaller = betweenArray[1] ? value <= +betweenArray[1] : true
      andResult = andResult && isBigger && isSmaller
    }
    orResult = orResult || andResult
  }

  return orResult;
}

function splitWithCondition(text, splitter, condition = value => value) {
  let arr = text.split(splitter)
  let result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (condition(arr[i])) {
      result.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: what does the brackets mean? Like are `"[70...80, 0...100]"` and `"70...80, 0...100"` and `"70...80 & 0...100"` the same??

Comment: *"I also tried creating a new recursive function to split the content of each pair of brackets in the strings but it also didn't work"*: Can you add your code and show what goes wrong with it?

Comment: This (parsing expressions) calls for a recursive descent parser rather than regular expressions, esp. if you're introducing parentheses and brackets.

Comment: no,
the "," is indicating an "or".
the "&" is indicating an "and".

the brackets should be used if I want to execute an "or" before an "and" for example,
because the default behaviour is executing the "and" first.

Comment: Please provide also the expected output for your privided examples ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your syntax to JS code:

```js
const inRange = (num, str) => {
  const subs = [
    ['&', ' && '],
    [/(?<=(?:\D|^))\.\.\.(\d+)/g, 'num <= $1'],
    [/(\d+)\.\.\.(?=(?:\D|$))/g, 'num >= $1'],
    [/(\d+)\.\.\.(\d+)/g, '$1 <= num && num <= $2'],
    [',', ' || '],
    ['[', ' ( '],
    [']', ' ) ']
  ];
  
  for(const [from, to] of subs){
    str = str.replaceAll(from, to);
  }
  
  console.log(str);
  
  const fn = new Function('num', 'return ' + str);
  
  return fn(num);
  
}

console.log(inRange(100, "0..."))
console.log(inRange(100, "...100"))
console.log(inRange(75, "0...100 & 70...80, 0...100 & [30...50, 60...90]"))
console.log(inRange(75, "0...100 & [70...80, 0...100] & 30...50"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Didn't knew there was a FunctionConstuctor in javascript.
Very simple and efficient. this is great! :D